# Foundation: content-less columns

Tags: zurb-foundation

I sometimes use columns as spacers, and so when there is no content, I don't want the column to collapse, which is the default behavior. Is there a built-in way to prevent empty columns from collapsing?

I know I can add some invisible div or something, but I'm asking if there's a standard way to accomplish this without resorting to hacks like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can use offsets to create gaps:](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html#offsets)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-1 columns">1</div>
  <div class="large-11 columns">11</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-1 columns">1</div>
  <div class="large-10 large-offset-1 columns">10, offset 1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-1 columns">1</div>
  <div class="large-9 large-offset-2 columns">9, offset 2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-1 columns">1</div>
  <div class="large-8 large-offset-3 columns">8, offset 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a hacky style for this. Like so:

```
.row.no-collapse .columns {
  min-height: 1px;
}

<div class="row no-collapse">
  <div class="large-1 columns">1</div>
  <div class="large-11 columns">11</div>
</div>
```